# Restkit mapping empty json list with relationship

Tags: core-data, mapping, restkit, empty-list

I've got a problem with empty json list mapping, I've got a JSON response  that look this way :

```
{
    id = 1;
    image = "http://image.com/image.png";
    name = "Test Category #1";
    "restricted_position" = 0;
    "restricted_time" = 0;
    restrictions =         {
        "restricted_position_detail" =             (
        );
        "restricted_time_detail" =             (
        );
    }
```

The mapping for the class look like this :

```
    +(RKManagedObjectMapping *)getObjectMapping
{
    RKObjectRelationshipMapping *restrictionMapping = [RKObjectRelationshipMapping mappingFromKeyPath:@"restrictions" toKeyPath:@"restrictions" withMapping:[Restriction getObjectMapping]];

    RKManagedObjectMapping *mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PLCategory class] inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"identifiant"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"image" toAttribute:@"imageUrl"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"restricted_position" toAttribute:@"restricted_position"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"restricted_time" toAttribute:@"restricted_time"];

    [mapping addRelationshipMapping:restrictionMapping];
    [mapping setPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"identifiant"];

    return mapping;
}
```

The mapping for the Restriction class :

```
    +(RKManagedObjectMapping *)getObjectMapping
{
    RKObjectRelationshipMapping *zg_mapping = [RKObjectRelationshipMapping mappingFromKeyPath:@"restricted_time_detail" toKeyPath:@"restricted_time_detail" withMapping:[GeographicalArea getObjectMapping]];
    RKObjectRelationshipMapping *ph_mapping = [RKObjectRelationshipMapping mappingFromKeyPath:@"restricted_position_detail" toKeyPath:@"restricted_position_detail" withMapping:[TimeSlot getObjectMapping]];
    RKManagedObjectMapping *mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Restriction class] inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore];
    [mapping addRelationshipMapping:zg_mapping];
    [mapping addRelationshipMapping:ph_mapping];

    return mapping;
}
```

No matter what I try I keep getting these annoying errors :

```
Core Data Save Error
                               NSLocalizedDescription:      The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1580.)
                               NSValidationErrorKey:            restricted_position_detail
                               NSValidationErrorPredicate:  (null)
                               NSValidationErrorObject:
<Restriction: 0xb9c2f20> (entity: Restriction; id: 0xb9b5d90 <x-coredata:///Restriction/tE6CDEA6C-5A2A-48AE-9454-A8E6CC35F5078> ; data: {
    category = "0xb9b67b0 <x-coredata:///PLCategory/tE6CDEA6C-5A2A-48AE-9454-A8E6CC35F5077>";
    "restricted_position_detail" =     (
    );
    "restricted_time_detail" =     (
    );
})
2013-07-08 12:39:00.716 [7442:28513] E restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectStore.m:263 Core Data Save Error
                               NSLocalizedDescription:      The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1580.)
                               NSValidationErrorKey:            restricted_time_detail
                               NSValidationErrorPredicate:  (null)
                               NSValidationErrorObject:
<Restriction: 0xb9c2f20> (entity: Restriction; id: 0xb9b5d90 <x-coredata:///Restriction/tE6CDEA6C-5A2A-48AE-9454-A8E6CC35F5078> ; data: {
    category = "0xb9b67b0 <x-coredata:///PLCategory/tE6CDEA6C-5A2A-48AE-9454-A8E6CC35F5077>";
    "restricted_position_detail" =     (
    );
    "restricted_time_detail" =     (
    );
})
```

What I'd like to do is map these empty list with an empty NSArray. Does anyone have a clue how to do that ? is it even possible ?

Comment: Give details of your data model. Are `restricted_position_detail` & `restricted_time_detail` transformable attributes or relationships. What attributes are set as optional?

Comment: restricted_position_detail & restricted_time_detail are non optional to-many relationships targeting respectively GeographicalArea and TimeSlot classes. The Restriction classes only contains theses two relationship and an inverse relationship with my PLCategory class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have made the relationships non-optional. By default they will be empty sets (not arrays), but if you try to save when the sets are empty you will get validation errors because you configured that the relationships have to have at least one connection (that's what non-optional means).

If you want to allow zero connections, make the relationships optional.

Note that you might wan't to make the other end of the relationships non-optional, so you know if you have a `GeographicalArea` or `TimeSlot` then it must be connected to a `Restriction`. This would usually tie in with a `Cascade` deletion rule.

Comment: Thank you Wain I've thought about making my relationships optional but since my doc said they should be mandatory I looked for a way to save empty set. Now I know it's impossible I can move on to some other issue.